# Haskell where type declaration

Tags: haskell, types, where-clause

I'm new to Haskell and having trouble with the type system.  I have the following function:

```
threshold price qty categorySize
    | total < categorySize = "Total: " ++ total ++ " is low"
    | total < categorySize*2 = "Total: " ++ total ++ " is medium"
    | otherwise = "Total: " ++ total ++ " is high"
    where total =  price * qty
```

Haskell responds with:

```
No instance for (Num [Char])
      arising from a use of `*'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Char])
    In the expression: price * qty
    In an equation for `total': total = price * qty
    In an equation for `threshold':
     ... repeats function definition
```

I think the issue is that I need to somehow tell Haskell the type of total, and maybe associate it with the type class Show, but I don't know how to accomplish that. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is you define `total` as the result of a multiplication, which forces it to be a `Num a => a` and then you use it as an argument to `++` with strings, forcing it to be `[Char]`.

You need to convert `total` to a `String`:

```
threshold price qty categorySize
    | total < categorySize   = "Total: " ++ totalStr ++ " is low"
    | total < categorySize*2 = "Total: " ++ totalStr ++ " is medium"
    | otherwise              = "Total: " ++ totalStr ++ " is high"
    where total    = price * qty
          totalStr = show total
```

Now, that will run, but the code looks a little repetitive. I would suggest something like this:

```
threshold price qty categorySize = "Total: " ++ show total ++ " is " ++ desc
    where total = price * qty
          desc | total < categorySize   = "low"
               | total < categorySize*2 = "medium"
               | otherwise              = "high"
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be that you need to explicitly convert between strings and numbers.  Haskell will not automatically coerce strings to numbers or vice versa.

To convert a number for display as a string, use `show`.

To parse a string into a number, use `read`.  Since `read` actually applies to many types, you may need to specify the type of the result, as in:

```
price :: Integer
price = read price_input_string
```